# Doctrine2 and MongoDB Query on embedded array of an embedded array of referenced documents in a Document

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, mongodb-query

I have a collection of `Customer` that have multiple `Order`.
The `Order` is an embedded array in the `Customer` collection.
Inside one `Order` there is an `@ReferencedMany` to the  `Product` collection.

I now want to do some reporting on every `Product` that a `Customer` has ever bought.

What would be the MongoDB way to find all the products for this customer and add filters on this query. I don't want to loop every order and then fetch all the products and put them in a Doctrine ArrayCollection.

Is there a direct way to query these products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo DB does not fetch references automatically in single query. Maybe some drivers support such functionality and may produce sub-query/ies transparent for user.

You can aggregate the data required for report to one collection using map-reduce pattern, for example, or embed Product data to Customer. But as consequence the queries on Product will become more complex.

You can de-normalize data and duplicate some Product data required for reports in Customer collection. Then you'll have to deal with synchronization of those collections.

Working on same issue, I came to the conclusion that if you want to reflect **relations** between objects you should use **relational** database :)